# Getting data from Flash that playing online

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stream, adobe, flash-builder

It somehow should be possible to get all data from Flash File that running currently in browser.

Get all data from rendered objects like values, positions and ect. The more inforamation the better

So what I think is if my computer my adobe flash render all this locally so I'm receiving already it to my computer so I need to read as adobe flash render this.

Comment: Look for memory dumper utilities, but then you will have to parse all that data. And yes, the majority of graphics are rendered client side. Pre-rendered bitmaps exist, but they are pretty large and you should be able to see if a flash app is downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how Scout works (some info [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html))
It opens a TCP/IP telemetry channel from which it receives all informations about the movie playing.
I suppose the data would be pretty hard to figure out, plus the movie would have to have the telemetry feature enabled ... but it's a start